# Внимание: ознакомьтесь с новыми нормами поведения

Tags: обсуждение

Уважаемые коллеги!

Обратите внимание на [новую страницу](https://rus.stackexchange.com/conduct) Справки, которая называется *нормы поведения* (Code of Conduct — английский эквивалент). Уделить ей внимание совершенно необходимо, ведь она проясняет многие моменты, связанные с ожидаемым от каждого поведением, которые ранее оставались в стороне. Более того, прочитав ее, вы поймете, как устроен процесс модерирования на нашем сайте и с помощью ярких примеров узнаете, как лучше поступить в некоторых частых ситуациях.

Любые предложения и замечания, связанные с нормами поведения, прошу оставлять под этим вопросом.

### *https://rus.stackexchange.com/conduct*

Comment: Спасибо за перевод! Я видел это чуть раньше на английском, но всё же с удовольствием перечитал на родном.

Comment: @Aer _...вы поймете, как устроен процесс модерированиЯ…_ Не смею править.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова спасибо!

Comment: Большое спасибо за перевод! Всё никак не находил время прочитать новые нормы в оригинале, а тут случайно подвернулась ваша ссылка. В переводе нашел несколько опечаток:1) "вне зависимости от уровня знаний и личностных качества" - последнее слово должно быть "качеств" без буквы "а" на конце; 2) В разделе "Неприемлемое поведение" подзаголовок "Никого преследования" должен, видимо, звучать "НиКАкого преследования.";3) В последнем блоке "Имея нормы поведения мы всегда можем подкорректировать нашу культуру, если она вдруг отклониться от намеченного курса." - "отклониться" - пишется без мягкого знака

Comment: Местами ещё знаки препинания расставлены, на мой взгляд, неправильно, но это уже наверное мелочи.

Comment: @EugeneEvdokimov спасибо! Ошибки будут исправлены. Если у вас есть другие замечания, пожалуйста, изложите их в отдельном вопросе здесь, на Мете.

Comment: @Aer Обновил строки на сайте! Спасибо за исправления!

Comment: @Aer Обратите внимание, обнаружилась описка: **Главая** — Вопросы — Метки — Участники — Без принятого ответа.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова исправил, спасибо!

Comment: А чегой-то не поменялась —как была **Главая** (слева, на основном поле), так и осталась.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова я исправил перевод в базе данных, но нужно подождать, когда она синхронизируется с сайтом )

Comment: @Aer, у меня возникла проблема с сайтом "Русский   язык". Задать на Мете вопрос тоже не могу. Программа выдает сообщение: " Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества...". Вы можете мне помочь?

Comment: @Серж это связано со слишком маленьким количеством символов. Пожалуйста, добавьте чуть больше текста и задайте вопрос на Мете. https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/345/178412

Comment: @Aer, текст не маленький, я видел вопросы и с меньшем текстом. Но я постараюсь, посмотрю.