# Предлагаю ослабить требования к длине вопроса на Мете

Tags: предложение, статус-так-задумано

Не знаю точно, какое минимальное количество символов требуется в основной части вопроса на Мете, но мои вопросы всегда короче этого минимума. К счастью, я нашел обходной путь: добавить много ненужных символов, сохранить вопрос, затем изменить его, убирая лишнее. Предлагаю ослабить требования к длине вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Ограничения на количество символов связано с тем, что очень часто короткие сообщения связаны со спамом или низкокачественны. Увы, автоматически определять те случаи, когда нормальное сообщение содержит мало символов, невозможно, поэтому использовать тот «лайфхак», который вы предложили, безусловно, можно и нужно.

В любом случае мы не можем установить пониженный порог только для нашего сайта, поэтому такие предложения стоит обсудить с участниками других сообществ.

Comment: По-моему, это ограничение действует только на Мете, а это странно.

Comment: @М_Г, действительно, не поймешь, какое минимальное количнство должно быть. Приходиться добавлять ненужнве символв, чтобы сохранить текст.Порой писать не хочется.