# Где "новые правила" сообщества?

Tags: поддержка

Узнал тут по случаю, что у сообщества появились какие-то "новые правила". 
Однако ж, в новом дизайне не нашел ссылки ни на новые, ни даже на старые. 
Может, ссылку дадите общедоступную?

(+)----------------

Странно, я даже вопрос не могу на Мете задать.

> Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества проекта. Убедитесь, что в
>   нём полностью описана проблема, а также ваши решения в грамматически
>   правильной форме.

Проблема описана, решения у меня нет.

С этим понятно. Коротковато сначала получилось. 
Но основной вопрос не снимаю.

Comment: Обратите внимание на этот вопрос: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/333/178412.

Comment: То есть "нормы поведения" - это правила?! Ну ладно, допустим, а ссылка на них где? Человек просто не пойдет искать то, о чем не имеет понятия. Остальное - в чате.

Comment: Ссылка: https://rus.stackexchange.com/conduct.

Comment: Aer, но помилуйте, я уже знаю, где єта страница, но как на не' попасть с главной страниціы?! Если это "правила" то они должны быть доступны в один клик.

Comment: знак вопроса — Справка — Code of conduct; или через страницу «Тур»; или через поиск по Справке по ключевым словам...

Comment: Да это понятно. Но кто ж будет без ваших пояснений искать таким образом? Новичку и в голову не придет. Тем более, что там и слова "правила" нет. А слово "нормы" - лишь частичный и не слишком употребительный синоним "правилам". Нет, как хотите, а на "правила" должна вести прямая ссылка.